# Do Flask forms really better than HTML forms?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I am new to Flask and I found this Flask_WTF or Flask Forms. I just dont see the need for it. We can do similar things with HTML. I understand that Flask forms have internal validations but we can provide better javascript client side validations which can validate data without server trip. What is the real need of using Flask Forms? Would not HTML forms will be better so we can provide inline styling if required and will be easy to use with bootstrap.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

You can use flask WTforms wherever and for whatever you need would need to use regular html forms.

There a a few handy things WTF forms provide like CSRF protection and easy to use macros etc.

You do not have to use them they just make some things easier

Same as asked here [Why use WTForms instead of just posting with HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45973346/why-use-wtforms-instead-of-just-posting-with-html)

Comment: Thanks. Its very helpful.